# как получить через google.maps.places город в 2х языках англ и русский

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps, геолокация

использую `var place = autocomplete.getPlace();`

как можно получить город на англ.яз и русском одновременно?

```
{address_components: [
  {long_name: "1", short_name: "1", types: Array(1)}
  {long_name: "Ploshchad' Privokzal'naya Stantsii Penza-1", short_name: 
  "Ploshchad' Privokzal'naya Stantsii Penza-1", types: Array(1)}
  {long_name: "Penza", short_name: "Penza", types: Array(2)}
  {long_name: "Penza", short_name: "Penza", types: Array(2)}
  {long_name: "Penzenskaya oblast'", short_name: "Penzenskaya oblast'", types: Array(2)}
  {long_name: "Russia", short_name: "RU", types: Array(2)}
  {long_name: "440000", short_name: "440000", types: Array(1)}
]}
```

использую название города для поиска по БД

Answer (score 0):

Примените селектор языка в линке карт Гугл. Например:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ВашКлюч&amp;language=ru&amp;callback=initialize"></script>
```

Здесь селектор: **language=ru**.

Comment: так он ведь начнет отдавать только на русском

Comment: попробуйте локализацию для регионов https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization#Region